# NodeJS Text Layout and Image Generation

Tags: node.js, text, aws-lambda

I am looking for the best approach for generating images of text on the server side (preferably Node.js).  It will need to accommodate things like paging (so generating multiple images of text for one text input if it is too long to fit on one page).  I am looking for something that is fairly precise and allows for a good deal of type configuration.

I have looked at a few options:

1. Use Canvas.  This approach would work for most of the use cases.  I could use a text engine like textjs for the layout.  However, this is somewhat limiting as Canvas doesn't have specific text metrics (for things like text height used for exact positioning).  This could make paging difficult.
2. Use normal HTML with something like PhantomJS to generate and them capture an image of the text.  While this approach will work for some use cases, it makes it hard to handle things like paging.
3. Use some other text engine.  I've looked around and found some options - but it would need to be something that I could call from Nodejs (as I'll likely use this on AWS Lambda).

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I lately did something very similar - also with node.js on Lambda. In my opinion the best approach is using PhantomJS and maybe taking the detour of generating a PDF.

With HTML and CSS you can conveniently style the output exactly how you want it, which is a great advantage about the way more complicated Canvas approach. You only have to take care of adding some horizontal space wherever you expect the pagebreak (of course this depends on your usecase and may not be necessary). Having the rendered HTML page you now have two options:

- You could generate a PDF - which will take care of generating multiple pages - and then rasterize that to images
- Or you directly generate an image with [Screen Capture](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) ([example Code](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js)) and then splitt that image horizontally

Both approaches worked fine for me.